# Difference between storyboard screen size and actual iPhone screen size

Tags: ios, storyboard

Can someone confirm that there's a notable difference between the size of the screen shown in the storyboard verse where the screen actually cuts off?

I have a 6SE, 6S, and 6 plus to test my projects, which have the same size screens as their 7 model counterparts. I found the following:

Regarding 7 plus:
Storyboard provides a screen whose height is 736 and width is 414. When running an app on my 6 plus only shows a height of 667 and width of 375 of the storyboard's screen (cutting off some of the bottom right).

Regarding 7:
Storyboard provides a screen whose height is 667 and width is 375 while running an app on my 6S only shows a height of 570 and width of 320.

Regarding SE:
This one had matching height and widths, meaning everything put onto the storyboard screen appears just like the storyboard shows it. Why does this one not have a discrepancy while the others do?

Does anyone know why there's this discrepancy between storyboard screen size and what actually shows up on iPhone 6 screens?

Is there a way to recalibrate the storyboard screen size so that screen sizes match for all 7 models and not just the SE? Does this discrepancy hold up when testing apps on the iPhone 7 series or does this relate to using the 6 series to test my app?

Thanks,
Mike

Below are links showing the discrepancy:
[Click here for the 7plus setting in storyboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDyUj.png).[Click here for the screen grab on a 6 plus after I made a green background so there's contrast where it gets cutoff.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCQ3h.png)

Comment: *"my 6 plus only shows a height of 666 and width of 360"* ... how are you determining this?

Comment: I think there's something amiss with your constraints in your storyboards.

Comment: It's an estimate based on filling in an empty storyboard with a lot of buttons and then seeing which of those buttons are visible when I load the Xcode project on my phone. It's probably +/- 3 or so. There's definitely stuff that gets cutoff.

Comment: onnoweb, is there a way to fix my constraints if they're amiss in my storyboard only?

Comment: When you run the app on your phone, do a screen-capture. Load that into an image editor, and verify that your buttons are remaining the size you think they are, and that the actual dimensions of the screen-cap image are what you think they are (and update your question with resulting images).

Comment: take a screen shot of any  app and open in preview and check size  and check storyboard size u will find exact size in both.

Comment: I've updated my post to include links to what I'm referencing with the 7 plus setting verse how it appears on the 6 plus.

Comment: Is what I'm describing what everyone faces when using Xcode or is it somehow just me? Is the answer just mastering autolayout? When I center things, they're not actually fully centered because of this discrepancy. Why would apple make this discrepancy? Makes no sense.

Comment: "Is the answer just mastering autolayout" Yes. This is what autolayout _is_. It lets you compensate for the fact that screens come in many sizes.

Comment: @michaeldebo - see my answer...

Answer (score 0):

On your physical device(s):

1. Open Settings...
2. select `Display & Brightness`...
3. Scroll down to `DISPLAY ZOOM`...

Is `View` set to `Standard` or `Zoomed`? I'm betting it is set to `Zoomed`...

Switch it to `Standard` and you will no longer have conflicting screen sizes.

Comment: That's what it was! Thank you kind sir!